# Getting creation date and last access date of a text file

Tags: file, text, .net, c#

I am trying to extract the creation time and last access time of a text file using .Net.I wrote the following code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{  
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo("C:\\file.txt");

            DateTime time = info.CreationTime;
            Console.WriteLine(time);

            time = info.LastAccessTime;
            Console.WriteLine(time);

            time = info.LastWriteTime;
            Console.WriteLine(time);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

01-01-1601 5:30:00
01-01-1601 5:30:00
01-01-1601 5:30:00

I am unable to understand why it's giving me output in this way and what's wrong with it?
How should I correct it?

Comment: Why are you posting a programming question on Superuser instead of Stackoverflow? I am going to vote to migrate but I guarantee you this question will be locked due to the low quality of it.  It seems like you are expecting something different but don't indicate what that is.

Comment: What do you mean by low quality question ? Can you solve it ?

Comment: Yes; it's low quality you don't indicate what you expected.  Yes; I already solved it the minute I looked at it.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx):

> If the file described in the FileSystemInfo object does not exist, this property will return 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

so my guess is you are in Eastern Time Zone, (GMT + 5.5hrs) based on the 05:30AM timestamp.

step through your code and make sure the file exists, and is accessible to the user running the program.

always check FileInfo.Exists() before attempting to use any of the values in the object.

consider putting an @ in front of the path string
eg: `@"c:\file.txt"`. the @ will abort any escape sequences.

Comment: using @"c:\file.txt" does not help.Please suggest something else.

Comment: did you check info.Exists() before evaluating the values? if it returns false, your issue is either that the file does not exist, or there is a permissions issue accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

- File might not exist. Check for the file existence first, then go for
  FileInfo.
- when you are using path use `@"C:\folder\file.txt"` or
  `"C:\\folder\\file.txt"`. Don't try to mix up both.

It is most likely one of the reasons above.